# How to force the installer to give yes for prompts, while installing packages with apt using yaml

Tags: apt

I have been trying to install a java package to a aws instance through ansible. The yaml script runs successfully but the outcome is not achieved. I guess that the issue is because of the Yes or No prompt. I need help for adding lines in the YAML script to force the installer to give yes for prompts

Comment: Use apt's '-y' flag to suppress the the Yes/No prompt.

Comment: I need to add scripts to supress the prompts in terms of YAML. We use -y flag when we use sudo apt command in ubuntu cli.